# Functional Programming: int to bignum conversions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm doing an exercise where I need to convert `int` to `bignum` in OCaml, for example:

> ```
> 123456789 -> {neg:false; coeffs:[123;456;789]}
> ```

There were a lot of things going inside my head when writing the function, and it was a load of fun. However, I'm not really sure if this is the cleanest, and fastest way to do this.

```
type bignum = {neg: bool; coeffs: int list};;
let base = 1000;;

let fromInt (n: int) : bignum =
  let rec aux num:int list=
    if num==0 then
       []
    else 
       abs (num mod base) :: aux (num/base)
  in
  {neg=n<0; coeffs=List.rev (aux n)}
;;
```

fromInt turns an `int` to a `bignum`. Things to note:

- I decided to mod the number with the base, and then divide the number
  by the base and use that as the input. This is so I can avoid having to do exponents on ints. Was actually pretty excited when I realized that.
- Used abs on (num mod base) every recursive call. Do you think there is a cleaner way of doing this? The the reason I didn't `abs` it on the first call was because `(-max_int) <> min_int`
- As you can see I'm using List.rev because I do it in reverse order. This is so I can avoid having snoc lists. I'm not really sure if it's the only way though so feel free to note me.

And here is `toInt`, which turns a `bignum` into an `int`.

```
let toInt (b: bignum) =
  let rec aux (b:int list) (p:int)=
     match b with
     |hd::[]-> Some (hd*p)
     |hd::tl-> (match aux tl (p*base) with
        |Some c-> let bint = (hd*p) in 
                  if bint < hd then None 
                  else Some (bint+c)
        |None -> None)
     |[]->Some 0
  in
  let {neg=n; coeffs=x} = b in
  let c = List.rev x in
     match aux c 1 with
     |Some c-> if n then Some (-c) else Some c
     |None -> None
;;
```

I'm particularly not fond of the nested match statements, and there is probably still room for cleanup. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

`num==0` is misleading, use `num=0` (although it has the same meaning for integers). Also, `fromInt` is spread over too many lines for my taste, I'd prefer the following choice of line breaks:

```
let fromInt (n: int) : bignum =
  let rec aux num : int list =
    if num=0 then []
    else abs (num mod base) :: aux (num/base) in
  {neg=n<0; coeffs=List.rev (aux n)}
```

This is fine for short lists of coefficients. In general tail recursion is preferred. I drop type annotations below. I add type annotations during debugging if I start getting confusing type errors, other than that I put types of functions in the interface (.mli).

```
let fromInt n =
  let rec aux acc num =
    if num=0 then acc
    else aux (abs (num mod base) :: acc) (num/base) in
  {neg=n<0; coeffs=aux n}
```

General note. I use the following kinds of line breaks with `if..then..else` depending on what fits in 80 columns and looks nice.

```
if test then blah
else blah

if test
then blah
else blah

if test
then
  blah
else
  blah
```

Now on to `toInt`. First, the way I would format it:

```
let toInt b =
  let rec aux b p =
    match b with
    | [] -> Some 0
    | hd::tl ->
      match aux tl (p*base) with
      | Some c->
        let bint = hd*p in 
        if bint < hd then None 
        else Some (bint+c)
      | None -> None in
  let c = List.rev b.coeffs in
  match aux c 1 with
  | Some c -> if b.neg then Some (-c) else Some c
  | None -> None
```

Again, it is interesting to explore the tail-recursive variant. I use my preferred style.

```
let toInt b =
  let rec aux acc p = function
    | [] -> Some acc
    | hd::tl ->
        let bint = hd*p in 
        if bint < hd then None 
        else aux (bint + acc) (p*base) tl in
  let c = List.rev b.coeffs in
  match aux 0 1 c with
  | Some c -> if b.neg then Some (-c) else Some c
  | None -> None
```